# Correct response to remote player quit in Game Center

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I have a turn-based match with two participants, *A* and *B*. It is currently *A*'s turn. *B* quits out of turn by calling:

```
[match participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit ... etc.
```

As far as *A*'s Game Center app is concerned, the match with *B* is still in play – the match status is `GKTurnBasedMatchStatusOpen`, and the match outcomes are `GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeNone` and `GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit` respectively.

From the documentation, it appears that participant *A* should detect this and call:

```
participantA.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
participantB.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit;

[self endMatchInTurnWithMatchData: ... etc.
```

However, there seems to be no notification for `participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome`, and periodically iterating through each match to end turns feels like a kludge.

What is the correct approach to ending these matches?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has a nice solution :)

First of all you set a handler

```
[GKTurnBasedEventHandler sharedTurnBasedEventHandler].delegate = self;
```

After which, you will get the callbacks

```
handleInviteFromGameCenter:
handleTurnEventForMatch:didBecomeActive:
handleMatchEnded:
handleTurnEventForMatch:didBecomeActive:
handleTurnEventForMatch:didBecomeActive:
player:receivedExchangeRequest:forMatch:
player:receivedExchangeCancellation:forMatch:
player:receivedExchangeReplies:forCompletedExchange:forMatch:
```

You need this method

```
handleMatchEnded:
```

To handle the match end on the opponent side.

Here is link to documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH15-SW12

Comment: Thank you! I have `handleMatchEnded:` implemented but had clearly either missed that it covered this case, or been the victim of sandbox flakiness. The bounty is yours :)

Comment: Please note, that the event type is "push", it means that it will not work on "iOS Simulator", try to test on real devices.